# How to create stored procedure using code first approach with Entity Framework Core

Tags: .net-core, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

I am working on an ASP.NET Core project with Entity Framework Core. I took the code first approach and I am able to create tables through it.

Now I want to create a stored procedure, as well as the already created stored procedure, which needs to be mapped.

Comment: The only way is to actually execute the `CREATE PROCEDURE` script. You may do that in a migration, but you still have to write the full script yourself. Instead of trying to write the script as a C# string though it's probably (a lot) better to write it in a text file with `.sql` extension so you get editor highlighting and even execution if the editor supports it (VS Code does)

Answer (score 1):

First add a migration: `add-migration stored-procedures` or something.
Then open the migration and enter your SQL to create or drop the stored procedure in the following way.

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
  migrationBuilder.Sql("SQL TO CREATE STORED PROC");
}

protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
  migrationBuilder.Sql("SQL TO DROP STORED PROC");
}
```